# Devise add authentication to creating a role

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, roles, cancan, role

I'm using devise and cancan as an authentication solution.

For devise I have added a role attribute, and created a constant ROLES:

```
#Migration for adding roles
class AddRoleToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :role, :string
  end 
end

#Users.rb
ROLES = %w[user staff]
```

I want to add a function to the signup page, such that for a person to create a user with the role "staff" he has to enter a secret key as well (probably like a secret code like "staffsecretkey" in a input text box)

Anyone know of a way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to do two things:

1) Override devise controllers

2) Customise your views

Check devise wiki in github. You should be able to find all the info you need right there. I'm answering you from my BlackBerry so I could no give you more details right now. But if you can't solve this with the answer I gave you. I'll give you a hand later.

Comment: I've tried that already.

Overrode the controllers and changed routes.rb

But i decided to go for creating a separate model altogether because the two roles would have quite differing attributes.

Comment: Thanks anyway (: I'll just accept your answer since it's probably valid.